# MVVMCross - Image Binding in iOS Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my ViewModel, I receive an Image URL in the property :
UserImage

In my ViewController using ‘SDWebImage’ nuGet package I’m able to bind my image

```
Img_UserImage.SetImage(new NSUrl(ViewModel.UserImage));
```

Now, since I receive image Url in my view model
How do I bind the image URL to my UIImage through MvvMCross Binding????

```
private void SetUpBinding()
    {
     var set = this.CreateBindingSet<UserProfileViewController, UserProfileViewModel>();
     set.Bind(Img_UserImage).For(v => v.Image).To(vm => vm.UserImage); // Here I need to bind it.
     set.Apply();
    }
```

Would really appreciate the help…Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to create your own TargetBinding class that knows how to bind this View.

This would look something like:

```cs
public class SDWebImageTargetBinding : MvxTargetBinding
{
    protected UIImageView ImageView => Target as UIImageView;

    public override Type TargetType => typeof(string);

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode => MvxBindingMode.OneWay;

    public SDWebImageTargetBinding(object target)
        : base(target)
    {
    }

    public override void SetValue(object value)
    {
        if (ImageView == null) return;

        if (value is string stringValue)
        {
            ImageView.SetImage(stringValue);
        }        
    }
}
```

Then in Setup.cs you would register it by overriding `FillTargetFactories`:

```cs
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
    base.FillTargetFactories(registry);

    registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<UIImageView>("ImageUrl", view => new SDWebImageTargetBinding(view));
}
```

Then you can bind with:

```cs
using var set = this.CreateBindingSet...
set.Bind(imageView).For("ImageUrl").To(vm => vm.UserImage);
```